# super() can't increment the class variable of parent class but it updates parent class' class dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, super

I am encountering a weird problem on this following code snippet:

```
class Magical_SportsPerson:
    database = {}
    playerNo = 0
    def __init__(self,name,team,jerseyNo):
        self.name = name
        self.team = team
        self.jerseyNo = jerseyNo
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "Name:{}\nTeam:{}\nJerseyNo:{}".format(self.name,self.team, self.jerseyNo)
    
class Quidditch_Player(Magical_SportsPerson):
    def __init__(self,name,team,jerseyNo,goals = None,retirement_date = "Not yet retired"):
        super().__init__(name,team,jerseyNo)
        super().playerNo += 1 # for some weird reason, super().playerNo is not working
        self.goals = goals
        self.retirement_date = retirement_date

        # create a player ID in the format of "playerNo + first letter of first name + first letter of last name + jersey number"
        self.playerID = str(super().playerNo) + self.name[0] + self.name[self.name.index(" ") + 1] + str(self.jerseyNo)

        # create a list of player details in the format of [name, team, jerseyNo, goals, retirement_date]
        self.playerDetails = [self.name, self.team, self.jerseyNo, self.goals, self.retirement_date]
        
        # add the player to the database
        super().database[self.playerID] = self.playerDetails

    def __str__(self):
        details = Magical_SportsPerson.__str__(self) + "\nGoals:{}".format(self.goals) + "\nRetirement Date:{}".format(self.retirement_date)
        return details
    
    @classmethod
    def createPlayer(cls,name,team,jerseyNo,goals = None ,retirement_date = "Not yet retired"):
        return cls(name,team,jerseyNo,goals,retirement_date)
```

Now, if run this code with any object like:

```
p1 = Quidditch_Player("Harry Potter","Gryffindor", 8, 523)
print("------Details of the player------")
print(p1)
```

I am getting the following error:
`AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'playerNo'`

but if I do `Magical_SportsPerson.playerNo += 1` it works fine.

My question is if `database` and `playerNo` both are class variables in parent class (here `Magical_SportsPerson`), then why `super().playerNo += 1` does NOT work but `super().database[self.playerID] = self.playerDetails` works properly?

`super().playerNo += 1` does not work, but `Magical_SportsPerson.playerNo += 1` works fine.

Comment: Its interesting that getting the attribute works (e.g `print(super().playerNo)` works), its only setting the attribute that fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `super().playerNo += 1` doesn't work is because `super()` returns a special object that just delegates getting attributes to the superclass and that special object doesn't allow setting attributes.
(link to the documentation for `super()`: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#super).

The reason `super().database[self.playerID] = self.playerDetails` does work is because you're getting the `.database` attribute on the superclass and setting one of its items. Notice that you're never actually *setting the attribute* on the superclass here (only modifying the attributes in place)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I am confused on the point that isn't `super().database[self.playerID] = self.playerDetails` adding (or, setting) new dict elements when it's not already there? Apologies if I am missing something very basic.

Comment: Yes, `super().database[self.playerID] = self.playerDetails` is adding or setting the elements of the dict. But it isn't setting the *attribute* on the special object returned by `super()`, it is only getting the attribute and since the attribute is a `dict` (which is mutable), you change the items inside the dict inplace without actually setting the attribute on the special object returned by `super()`. In other words, its changing the items inside the dict without setting the attribute (only setting the attribute is disallowed, modifying the items of the attribute is allowed).

Comment: I see. So, what I get is, since we are adding or setting elements **inside** the dictionary, it's allowing us as it's not directly touching the class variable. (*Somewhat a bypass, I would call)*, but in the case of `playerNo`, it's directly touching the variables, that's why the error.